# How do I make a custom alias to print out a full path with custom text?

Tags: linux, shell

I want to make a alias for example if I type fullList it will print out a custom text with specific extension in  full path listed the last modified the last something like

```
>fullList

file = /home/user/something/fileA.txt &
file = /home/user/something/fileB.txt &
file = /home/user/something/fileC.txt & <- the last modified.
```

Comment: Sounds like `ls` or `find`, but to be honest I do not understand your question completely. "Custom text"? "full path"? I think you have to be a bit more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your exact example output, you're going to want to do something like.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo
for i in $(ls -trF *.txt); do 
  full_path="$(pwd $i)/$i"   
  echo "file = $full_path &"
done
```

And if you want to do a simple one line alias, do something like below.

```
> alias fullList="echo; for i in \$(ls -trF *.txt); do full_path=\"\$(pwd \$i)/\$i\"; echo \"file = \$full_path &\"; done"
> fullList

file = /some/path/oldest.txt &
file = /some/path/newer.txt &
...
file = /some/path/newest.txt &
```

Note, this is assuming you only want to find files, since the *F* flag for *ls* appends "/" to directories.

Answer (score 1):

### Function

Use a [`function`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CompoundCommands#Functions) instead of an `alias`. Henceforth, you will be able to pass argument

```
fullList() {
  customText="$1"

  for f in "$PWD"/* # list current dir files
  do 
      printf "%s: %s\n" "$customText" "$PWD/$f"
  done
}
```

#### Usage

Then run

```
$ fullList 'blabla'
blabla: /path/to/file1
blabla: /path/to/file2
blabla: /path/to/file2
```

#### Do you know about ?

The [`tree` command](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/tree.htm#03) ? Could be helpful to list directories content:

```
tree -f -L 1 $(pwd)/
```

> ```
> /home
> |-- /home/user1
> `-- /home/user2
> ```